# Decimal to Scientific Notation

Tags: perl

I need to convert decimal values to scientific notation:

Source coding: `\num{0.000002753}`

My Code (Referred in Internet):

```
use Number::FormatEng qw(:all);
print format_eng(0.000002753); 
print "\n";
```

Converted Output is: `2.753e-6`

However, my expected output is: `2.75*10^{-6}`

Could someone provide the way to sort this issue out?

Comment: Like `sprintf('%.2e', 0.000002753) =~ s/[eE]([-+]?)0*(\d+)\z/*10^{$1$2}/r`?

Comment: Uh... try printing the result? Or assigning it to a variable or whatever?

Comment: [Number::FormatEng](https://metacpan.org/pod/Number::FormatEng) is for **engineering** notation, not **scientific** notation; there is a subtle difference.

Answer (score 1):

Credits goes to [@melpomene from the comments on my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53391900/decimal-to-scientific-notation-in-perl-script?noredirect=1#):

```
while($val=~m/\\num{([^{}]*)\}/g)
{
    my $nums = $1;
    my $vals = sprintf('%.2e', $nums) =~ s/[eE]([-+]?)0*(\d+)\z/*10^{$1$2}/r;

    print "OrgVals: $nums\t: ConvVals: $vals\n";
}

OrgVals: 0.000002753    : ConvVals: 2.75*10^{-6}
OrgVals: 0.000004784    : ConvVals: 4.78*10^{-6}
OrgVals: 0.000050934    : ConvVals: 5.09*10^{-5}
```